# Set ticks that aren't at powers of some base on a loglog plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting over a small range, but I'm using a log-log plot to make certain features more clear. How can I set ticks on the x-axis that aren't powers of any base, but *multiples* of some value?

Basically, I want labels on the x-axis at the values `[x * 1E13 for x in range(1,10)]`.

Comment: Is the plot meant for interactive use? In other words; does the mouse-over values in an interactive plot have to be precise? This makes a difference as to how to format the ticklabels on the x-axis. Also, please include your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [FixedLocator](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator) and call `set_major_locator` on your x axis with it.

```
my_xaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator([x * 1E13 for x in range(1,10)]))
```

If you want labels, you need to set them manually:

```
labels = FixedFormatter(['{:5.2e}'.format(x * 1E13) for x in range(1,10)])
my_xaxis.set_major_formatter(labels)
```

Comment: Along with `major_locator` you might need to set `major_formatter`.